# Capture event and prevent code execution after trigger

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have a simple trigger

```
$("button").click(function()
{
    $(this).trigger("my_click"); //line A

    console.log("xxx"); //line B
});
```

Then I capture that event

```
$("button").on("my_click", function()
{
    console.log("custom"); //line X
});
```

But, is it possible to prevent the log of "xxx" being executed from the `.on()` function?

I want line A and line B to be executed aways, as it normally does. But in certain scenarios, I would like to execute line A, line X and prevent line B to be executed next. Is that even possible?

Comment: Well you could use a flag, set flag to false in my_click, check the flag before console of xxx

Answer (score 2):

You could use a flag to do this. Just check if flag is true or not before console of xxx and set the flag to false in your my_click

```js
var flag = true;

$("button").click(function()
{
    $(this).trigger("my_click"); //line A

    if( flag ) {
        console.log("xxx"); //line B
    }
});


$("button").on("my_click", function()
{
    console.log("custom"); //line X
    flag = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>button</button>
```